# Problem generating UFO files & FeynRules

Tags: warning-messages

I am trying to generate the right UFO files from a given Lagrangian properly written in FeynRules format. I'm obtaining the following message:

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve this? I have Mathematica 11.2, Ubuntu 16.04 in a 64-bit machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Any code you would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the FeynRules authors pointed me in an email, it is very likely that there is an incompatibility between Mathematica 11 and FeynRules 2.3. The problem was solved installing Mathematica 10 (or an earlier version).